# VBA: DateDiff does not return exact working days

Tags: excel, vba

my general manager asked me to track the working days of our company's current projects that is recorded in an excel file and he wanted to me to make a new column for the remaining working days. I tried to make below code a function from the net to get the range of the days:

```
Function RDays(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Long
    RDays = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2)
End Function
```

but the results that i only get a value of 31 as a maximum days and when the value is greater than 31, the value returns to 1..

What would be the problem of this code?

Comment: If you want the number of days between two dates, subtract the earliest from the latest.

Comment: @Jeeped `DateDiff` is supposed to do the subtraction for you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You function works as expected for me. In A1 I put `9/20/2010` and in `A2` I put `9/30/2015`. In A3 I put `=RDays(A1,A2)`. It evaluates to 1836 which is 5*365 + 10 + 1 (for the leap day in 2012). The problem must be in how you are using it. So -- how *are* you using it?

Comment: Why can't you use `=DATEDIF(A1,A2,"d")` directly as a formula?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij That wouldn't work because you can't directly use a built-in VBA function in a formula. On the other hand, you *can* simply use `=DAYS(A1,A2)`, so this question is doubly mysterious. It is a mystery why OP is using VBA at all and it is a mystery why the VBA that they are using doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @JohnColeman, the `DATEDIF` function shrivallabha.redij is referencing is actually a worksheet function, *not* a VBA function (like the one OP is using). The MS documentation for it is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c), with some more background by ExcelJet posted [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function).

Comment: @TotsieMae You are correct that there is a `DATEDIF` function but it seems as if that function is somewhat depreciated and is only there for backwards compatibility. It is hidden from autocomplete and it doesn't appear in the menu of functions to be used when working with dates (I checked on those functions before making that comment). Thanks for pointing it out. I wonder how many other "hidden" functions there are like that.

Comment: Chip Pearson's site describes it this way: "For some reason, Microsoft has decided not to document this function in any other versions [other than Excel 2000]. DATEDIF is treated as the drunk cousin of the Formula family. Excel knows it lives a happy and useful life, but will not speak of it in polite conversation." (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx)

Comment: @JohnColeman TotsieMae is correct. Anyway, this post is ambiguous. OP says working days but in reality is looking at difference between two dates. `NETWORKSDAYS` or `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` in later versions of Excel are more appropriate if one is looking at working days (as any normal workplace would have weekly offs)!

Comment: As @JohnColeman wrote earlier, the problem is not in your code.  The problem may be in how you are calling the function, or displaying the result.  Your code works properly within VBA.  How, exactly, are you calling this function.  For example, if, on your worksheet, you were using something like `=DAY(RDays(A1,A2))`, then you would see your incorrect results.

Comment: So what two dates are you using that are returning `1` as the answer when the resulting answer should really be greater than `31`?

Answer (score 2):

The excel in-built `NETWORKDAYS(start_date, end_date, [holidays])` function will work perfectly well for returning the number of working days between two dates.

More info: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7

Answer (score -3):

Well, for one thing, it's Datedif in Excel, not Datediff, which is SQL Server.

Here is the general function, with arguments:

```
=DATEDIF (start_date, end_date, unit)
```

Here are the arguments, in units:

```
Unit    Return value
"Y"     Difference in complete years
"M"     Difference in complete months
"D"     Difference in days
"MD"    Difference in days, ignoring months and years
"YM"    Difference in months, ignoring days and years
"YD"    Difference in days, ignoring years
```

Comment: `DateDiff` actually *is* in VBA, so the OP wasn't incorrect there. You can find some documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datediff-function).